# Call a method with element as parameter

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I have this:

```
final Button myButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.mybutton);
```

How can I pass `myButton` into a method as a parameter? So I can use it inside a method to do something.

Like, I can call my method `hideThis()` as `MyClass.hideThis(myButton)` and it hides the given object.
So, how can i declare the method with the element as the parameter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you'd better refer to documentation and [Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/intro/index.html) tutorials.

But in your case, you can try:

```
public class VisibilityManager {
    public static void hide(View view){
        view.setVisibility(View.GONE); 
    }

    public static void show(View view){
        view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); 
    }
}
```

And then call this like:

```
final Button mybutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.mybutton);
// you can do it because `Button extends View`.
VisibilityManager.hide(mybutton);
```

Read more: [View#setVisibility(int)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setVisibility(int))

Comment: Could just be a static method, really, don't need the instance

Comment: @AndriiAbramov But what if its not only the `Button` ?? Sometimes i have to pass `EditText` and sometimes `Button`

Comment: @Ninooppgeorge all views in Android extend View class. Read about it in Android documentation -  https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html . See a solution in my answer.